# Javascript - Why use string as function name

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm working on a dojo project and stumbled on code below:

```
format: function ( /*Date*/ value, /*locale.__FormatOptions*/ constraints) {
    ....
},

"parse": function ( /*String*/ value, /*locale.__FormatOptions*/ constraints) {
   .....
},
```

As you can see parse method name is a string. I haven't seen something like this before. Is there any reason for doing this?

[Link to original file](http://code.openhub.net/file?fid=uvqUTQIXP34z2S4SbkrczkYRQ64&cid=elyU994P3M0&s=&fp=286566&mp&projSelected=true#L0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to JavaScript / ECMAScript standard, object property (or functions) identifiers (as used before the colon `:` in your example) can be any *valid* **identifier** (i.e. like the `format` without quotes), any **string** (like `"parse"`) or even any **number**.

Using `"parse"` in that case is strictly equivalent as using `parse`, but that would have been different in the case for example of `"parse that value"`, which is a valid string identifier for an object property, even though it has spaces!

Then you can use either `myObject.parse` or `myObject["parse"]` to access your property, whereas in my last example you have no choice but using `myObject["parse that value"]` to access it.

I think we should also mention a specific case where using quotes for object keys is different from *without* quotes: if you were to use Google Closure minifier in ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS mode, it would **replace** any non-quoted identifier to try and save space, whereas it would leave intact quoted identifiers, as Google team took this as the indicator that you will try to access it later on with the square brackets method and string, or if you check the actual key name like this:

```js
for (var i in myObject) {
    if (i === "parse") { // if i is replaced by the minifier, you will never execute the block below
        // do something...
    }
}
```

This specificity which forces you to use quoted identifiers sometimes (but not always, if you do not need to keep the original name) is one of the reasons that push people not using this advanced optimizations mode.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason for using extra quotes.

JSON requires it, but your object literal is not JSON. ES3 required this for keywords, but `parse` never was a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case there is no reason to do that, but I've faced scenarios where I needed to use quotes to define elements. For example:

```
var httpHeadersToAdd= {
  'User-Agent': 'whatever',
   Date: new Date()
};
```

With no quotes the interpreter understands that your are trying to do a subtract operation with variables `User` and `Agent` and throws a syntax error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token -`. Same can be made with functions, and then you have to call them with brackets:

```
var obj= {
  'my-function': function (){}
}

obj['my-function']();
```

Going back to the code you linked, maybe someone wrote that in a JSON-ish way because that's how JSON strings looks like (double quotes are mandatory in JSON, single quotes don't work)